# Compress multipage tiff

Tags: matlab, compression, tiff, libtiff

For faster loading of images in MATLAB I am using multi-page TIFF files which for me work much faster than MATLAB's simple imread. But my problem is that the size of the TIFF file is way bigger than normal images ( like ten times more ) so I'm looking in compression options. I have tried some of those options ( with the code I attached below ) some of them don't work and produce empty files and the rest kill the speed.

Is there any way to have both size and speed?

Thank you

P.S: I put my codes here. If I'm doing sth wrong please tell me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "tiffio.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define XSIZE 1280
#define YSIZE 720
#define NPAGES 1000
#define CHANNEL 3

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
uint32 image_width, image_height;
float xres, yres;
uint16 spp, bpp, photo, res_unit;
TIFF *out;
int i, j;
uint16 page;
Mat img;
int COMPRESSION_TAG = atoi(argv[1]);

unsigned char *array = new unsigned char [XSIZE * YSIZE*3];

char name[20];

out = TIFFOpen("myfile.tif", "w");
image_width = XSIZE;
image_height = YSIZE;


spp = CHANNEL; /* Samples per pixel */
bpp = 8; /* Bits per sample */
photo = PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK;
for (page = 0; page < NPAGES; page++)
{
    sprintf(name, "5_29%03d.jpg", page);
    img = imread(name);
    array = img.data;
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, image_width );
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, image_height);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, bpp);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, spp);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, photo);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_BOTLEFT);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_TAG);
    /* It is good to set resolutions too (but it is not nesessary) */
    xres = yres = 100;
    res_unit = RESUNIT_INCH;
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, xres);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, yres);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT, res_unit);

    /* We are writing single page of the multipage file */
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SUBFILETYPE, FILETYPE_PAGE);
    /* Set the page number */
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, page, NPAGES);

    for (j = 0; j < image_height; j++)
        TIFFWriteScanline(out, &array[3*j * image_width], j, 0);

    TIFFWriteDirectory(out);
}

TIFFClose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are comfortable with libtiff, you could give the Tiff class a try: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiffclass.html , If you are not happy with it, it should be easy to debug/convert to C code since the API is built on top of libtiff.

Comment: On the C code above, I would recommend using tiles (http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/libtiff.html#tiles) with compression.

Comment: you can try TIFFWriteTile given std. tile size